# The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Future in my Stateful Widget that I want to pass on to another class.

The Problem is that this class is in another Widget.
So when I want to pass on the data I get the

> The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Exception

Here the Code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<List> modelle;
  const HomeScreen({Key? key, required this.modelle,})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Favorites(),
    BodyHomeScreen(modelle: widget.modelle),
    Kontakt(),
  ];
```

The problem is the line where I want to access my List

```
widget.modelle
```

Any suggestions how I can fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup the list inside initState() function.

```
late List<Widget> _widgetOptions ;

@override
initState(){
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Favorites(),
    BodyHomeScreen(modelle: widget.modelle),
    Kontakt(),
  ];

}
```

Comment: BTW How can I access the _widgetOptions variable when its in the initState method?

Comment: It is only initialized in initState! It is having the scope into the class _HomeScreenState. Inside the class it can be used in methods like initState, build, or any custom.

Comment: Figured it out, dumb question ;)